# Show that on an infinite set $X$,the set of all possible metrics has a cardinality of $2^X$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, cardinals, alternative-proof

Consider the following problem:

Let $X$ be a set of infinite cardinality,then the set $M(X)$ of all possible metric functions on $X$ has cardinality of $2^X$.

Proof: Suppose $\scr S\subset$$ \mathbb 2^X$ ,where $\scr S$ is a set containing all non-empty non-singleton subsets of $X$ and satisfies the property that if $A\in \scr S$,then $X-A\notin \scr S$.For each $A\in \scr S$ define $d_A$ as follows:

$d_A(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=y$} \\[3ex]
1, & \text{if both $x,y$ are in $A$ or both in $X-A$ and $x\neq y$}\\[3ex]
2,& \text{if only one of $x$ and $y$ is in $A$}\end{cases}$

Verify that it is a metric for each $A\in \scr S$.

Also see that $A\mapsto d_A$ is an injective map from $\scr S $$\to M(X)$.So,$|M(X)|\geq |\scr S|$$=|2^X|=2^{|X|}$.

Also $|M(X)|\leq |\mathbb R|^{|X\times X|}=c^{|X|}=2^{\aleph_0 .|X|}=2^{|X|}$.

So,$M(X)$ has the cardinality of $2^X$.

Is the solution correct?Can someone give an alternative solution?

Comment: Your map is not quite injective, due to a symmetry between $A$ and $X - A$. If $X - A \in \scr S$ as well, then $d_A = d_{X - A}$.

Comment: @user771918 Then consider the set in which if I take $A$,I will not take $X-A$.Since $A\to X-A$ is a one-one correspondence,it would halve the cardinality of $\scr S$ which is same as cardinality of $\scr S$.

Comment: See Theorem 1 (pp. 16-17) in the following paper: Tibor Šalát, János T. Tóth, and László Zsilinszky, [*On cardinality of sets of metrics generating metric spaces of prescribed properties*](http://annalesm.elte.hu/annales35-1992/Annales_1992_T-XXXV.pdf), **Annales Universitatis Scientiarium Budapestinensis de Rolando Eötvös Nominatae. Sectio Mathematica** 35 (1992), pp. 15-21.